# Parsing a tab delimited text file with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse a text file.  First I plan on extrcating each line, then extracting each field by searching for a tasb.

When I use InStr to sercah for a \r (return for end of line) or \t (for tab) I always get a zero.  But if I put in a visable letter such as a I got a 5.
also I tried /r, /n and \n all return a zero.
The file looks as follows:

```
ID  Name
1   Patient
2   Bed
3   PatientSet
4   BedSet
5   TriggerSet
6   Triggering
7   Panel
```

the code

```
 fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("D:\BW\bwdatabase\ContextType.txt")
    MsgBox(fileReader)

    Str = fileReader
    i = InStr(Str, "\r") // i uis zero
    l = Mid(Str, 0, i - 1) // so this crashes becouse index is -1
    MsgBo
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio/VB are you using? It makes a huge difference in my response if you have access to 2010 and can use iterator blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\r" does not work in VB. For \r, use vbCr; for \n, use vbLf.

Answer (score 5):

Look into using the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx#Y0) class. It will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: +1. The [MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) shows how to read CSV, just change the delimiter from comma to tab. In VB use the constant vbTab for the tab character. You can't use \t in a string in VB