# Using an array to search a file VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a program that needs to look through a text file line by line, the lines look like this:

```
10-19-2015  Brett Reinhard  All Bike    Yoga    Run the Studio  Design Your Own Strength
```

These are separated by tabs in the text file.

What I want to do is look at the second value, in this case "Brett Reinhard" and move the full line to another textfile called "Brett Reinhard"

I was thinking of using an array to check to see if the second 'column' in the line matched any value within a given array, if it does I want to perform a specific action.

The way I am thinking of doing this is with a For/next statement, now while it will work it will be a laborious process for the computer that I will be using it on.

The code I am thinking of using looks like this:

```
For intCounter=0 to Whatever Number is the last number of the array

    If currentfield.contains(array(intCounter)) Then

        Open StreamWriter(File directory & array(intcounter) & ".txt")

        Streamwriter.Writeline(currentfield)

    End IF
```

Is there a better way of doing this, such as referencing the second 'column' in the line, similar to the syntax used in VBA for excel.

```
Name=Cells(1,2).Value
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185403/parsing-a-tab-delimited-text-file-with-vb-net) about parsing a tab-delimited text file. It recommends using a [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx#Y0) and I'd recommend the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while its not using an array to search a file, what I ended up doing works just as well. I ended up using the split method thanks to @Martin Soles.

Here is what I came up with:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim intCount As Integer = 1
    Dim words As String
    Dim split As String()
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                      "I:\Games, Events, & Promotions\FRP\Back End\Approved.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow

                    words = currentField
                    split = words.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbTab)})

                    For Each s As String In split
                        If intCount = 2 Then
                            Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
                            file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("I:\Games, Events, & Promotions\FRP\Back End\" & s & ".txt", True)
                            file.WriteLine(currentField)
                            file.Close()
                        End If
                        intCount = intCount + 1
                    Next s
                    intCount = 1
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
              FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
    "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

End Sub 'Main
```

Thank you guys for the suggestions.

For right now the split method will work for what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that a line will only use the tab characters as field separators, you can do something along this:

1. Open the stream for reading text
2. Open a stream for writing text
3. Read a line of text
4. Use the Split method to break the incoming line into an array of fields
5. If the second element in the array is your sentinel value, write the original line to the writer
6. Repeat yourself until you have reached the end of file (ReadLine will return Nothing, or null for those c# folk).
7. Close and dispose of your stream objects.

If you aren't sure of the format, you will want to take the hit and use the TextFieldParser as mentioned in an earlier comment.